# How to get size of screen in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I display images loaded from a cloud storage in a full-page mode. I can provide a parameter to an image URL to request a specific size, e.g. match the longest screen dimension. This way I don't have to load 1920px image if the screen is only 1334 pixels.

How can I get the screen size to pass as a parameter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`MediaQuery`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html) class, along with the associated [`MediaQueryData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html) to determine your screen size and fetch the correct image. You can then compare the `MediaQueryData.size` member with some predefined screen sizes - this will give you the number of logical pixels.

For example, in the build method of a widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // retrieve the mediaQuery data
     final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
     if (mediaQueryData.size < const Size(100.0, 100.0)) {
       // build small image.
     } else {
       // build big image.
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Apparently I can simply use `double size = mediaQueryData.size.longestSide * mediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWork extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWork({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWork> createState() => _MyWorkState();
}

class _MyWorkState extends State<MyWork> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toInt(); // remove .toInt() and convert type to double for extra precision
    int screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toInt();
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("$screenHeight, $screenWidth")));
  }
}
```