# Flutter - How to setup a custom height and width of Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm aware that MediaQuery solutions exist to problems, however, I want to limit the size of my Scaffold so that it can be used for web-based apps as well. Similar to what Instagram has, can anyone help me with it?
[image]

Comment: You can use 'AspectRatio' as well, to maintain the aspect ratio of the app on each platform. This may prevent breaking of some widgets making UI unresponsive. You can use AspectRatio with media queries, like getting the available height of viewport and setting that height of SizedBox, and lastly, adding AspectRatio as a child of that SizedBox.

Comment: I recommend you use SizedBox with media query and Container as a child.  The pattern I see is Row : SizedBox with image and a SizedBox and textfields and a button, a GridView, and lastly tab navigation.  Maybe five segments on the form

Comment: can you scroll off screen with the gridview or is it a single page app.   The Gridview can be contained within a SizedBox keeping it on the single page.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried wrapping your `Scaffold` in `SafeArea` with a `minimum` property of `EdgeInsets.all(32.0)`?

For me, this recreates your mockup on any screen

Example code:

```dart
//...
return SafeArea(

  minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),

  child: Scaffold(
    //...
  ),
);
//...
```

Comment: I think this solution make the app bar look funny in chrome web

Comment: So this works however the UI is quite irresponsive

Comment: @Arnav if you're talking about dynamic screen size, then yes if used exactly as is, it doesn't respond to screen size, but you always have the MediaQuery functionality as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664059/how-to-get-size-of-screen-in-flutter-app), unless you mean in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and this happens to solve it: Place your bottomsheet in a scaffold and safearea

```
SafeArea(
bottom: false, // this to remove default bottom padding
//this should be your desired padding height from top to all background page still show
minimum: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.09),
child: Scaffold(
backgroundColor:
Colors.transparent,
extendBody: true,
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
body: YourBottomSheetContent()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used sizedboxes to create layers for a single page look.   The gridview does not shrink to the size of the window.  Instead it activates scrolling.  My solution works for chrome web.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme:ButtonTextTheme.primary,
          buttonColor:Colors.yellow,
        )
      ),
      home:  Test_SinglePage(),
    );
  }
}
class DataRecord{
  String name;
  String number;
  DataRecord(this.name,this.number);
}
class Test_SinglePage extends StatefulWidget {
  Test_SinglePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test_SinglePage> createState() => _Test_SinglePageState();
}


class _Test_SinglePageState extends State<Test_SinglePage> {
   List<DataRecord> lstData=[
    DataRecord("A","1"),    DataRecord("B","2"),    DataRecord("C","3"),    DataRecord("D","4"),
    DataRecord("E","5"),    DataRecord("F","6"),    DataRecord("G","7"),    DataRecord("H","8"),
    DataRecord("I","9"),    DataRecord("J","10"),    DataRecord("K","11"),    DataRecord("L","12"),
    DataRecord("M","13"),    DataRecord("N","14"),    DataRecord("O","15"),    DataRecord("P","16"),
    DataRecord("Q","17"),    DataRecord("R","18"),    DataRecord("S","19"),    DataRecord("T","20"),
    DataRecord("V","21"),    DataRecord("X","22"),    DataRecord("Y","23"),    DataRecord("Z","24"),
  ];

  Widget _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context, String name)
  {
      return SimpleDialog(
        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.zero,
        children:[
        Container(width:80,height:80,child:
        Column(children:[
        Text(name),
        SizedBox(height:20),
        Expanded(child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){ Navigator.of(context).pop();}, child: 
            Text("Close"))
          ],))
        ])
        )]);
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context,int index)
   {
     return
     GestureDetector(
       onTap:()=>showDialog(context:context,builder:(context)=>_dialogBuilder(context,lstData[index].name)),
      child:Container(color:Colors.grey,child:GridTile(child: Center(child:
     Column(children:[
     Text(lstData[index].name,style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2),
     Text(lstData[index].number,style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4)
     ])
     ))));
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title:Text("Single Page")),body: 
    Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom:10.0),
      child:
      Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [

          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child:Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:[
              
            FittedBox(
                fit:BoxFit.fitHeight,
              child:SizedBox(
                width:200,
                height:200,
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/apple.jpg"),
              )),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children:[
              Row(

              children: [
                SizedBox(height:100,width:200,child:Container(color:Colors.red,child:Text("reached"))),
                SizedBox(height:100,width:200,child:Container(color:Colors.blue,child:Text("reached2"))),
                SizedBox(height:100,width:200,child:Container(color:Colors.green,child:Text("reached3")))
              ],),
              Row(children: [
                 SizedBox(width:600, child:ElevatedButton(
                   
                   onPressed:(){

                  },child:Text("Press Me")))],)

              ])
          ])),
      
      Expanded(child:SizedBox(
        height:400,
        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,child:
      GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 300,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
      itemCount: lstData.length,
      itemBuilder: _itemBuilder
      )))],)
    ,));
  }
}
```